# React native pusher - private channel subscription with laravel passport oauth - http response detail

Tags: laravel, react-native, httpresponse, pusher, laravel-passport

I keep having 500 error when I try to subscribe to a private channel with pusher in my react native app. Back end is laravel with passport oauth server.

I have setup my auth end point in my pusher settings (http://url/broadcasting/auth)

**react-native pusher setup**

```
import Pusher from 'pusher-js/react-native';

Pusher.logToConsole = true;

var pusher = new Pusher('pusher-key', {
    authEndpoint:  'http://url.com/broadcasting/auth',
    cluster: 'ap1',
    encrypted: true
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('private-order');

channel.bind('App\\Events\\Order\\SiteHasAnsweredCheckIn', function(data) {
    console.log('ok : ' + data);
});
```

and the broadcast authorization route in my routes/channel.php file with a callback simply returning true but I keep having a 500 error

**routes/channels.php**

```
Broadcast::channel('order', function () {
    return true;
});
```

**Here is the event class**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events\Order;

use App\Site;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;

class SiteHasAnsweredCheckIn implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $site;

    public $user;

    public $checkInConfirmed;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param Site $site
     * @param User $user
     * @param $checkInConfirmed
     */
    public function __construct(Site $site, User $user, $checkInConfirmed)
    {
        $this->site = $site;

        $this->user = $user;

        $this->checkInConfirmed = $checkInConfirmed;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('order');
    }
}
```

The feedback from the console saying: "Pusher : Couldn't get auth info from your webapp : 500" is not really useful for debbuging. So difficult to point out what is wrong. If you have any idea?

If not, how could I get more information/feedback from the http response from the pusher response?

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

After the answer below, I have updated the route as follow. Please note api/* routes got no csrf token check as I excluded them from the middleware.

Still get a 500 error. Any way to have more details about the error thrown by Pusher? It would be useful to have some more feedback to understand what is going on.

**New auth Endpoint:**

```
Route::post('api/authtest', function() {

    $pusher = new Pusher(config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.key'), config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.secret'), config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.app_id'));
    echo $pusher->socket_auth($_POST[request()->channel_name], $_POST[request()->socket_id]);

})->middleware('auth:api');
```

**EDIT 2:**

I made it working by removing the middleware of authorization.

```
Route::post('api/authtest', function() {

    $pusher = new Pusher(config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.key'), config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.secret'), config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.app_id'));
    echo $pusher->socket_auth($_POST[request()->channel_name], $_POST[request()->socket_id]);

});
```

But obviously, the idea is to be able to get the user making such request so I can give proper authorization.

Here is how I pass my auth token to the pusher call from react-native but I get a 401 response.

```
let token = 'auth_access_token_taken_from_database';

var pusher = new Pusher('pasher_key', {
    authEndpoint: 'http://url.com/api/authtest',
    auth: {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    },
    cluster: 'ap1',
    encrypted: true
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('private-order');
```

All my other oauth get and post requests with this middleware and token given above are working properly with my axios calls.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The authentication endpoint can't simply return `true`. It must return a special token generated by the pusher library on your server. The client uses this token to demonstrate to the pusher API that it's allowed to connect to the private channel. Check out this [documentation](https://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users#implementing_private_endpoints).

Comment: thanks for your answer but I'm still stuck. I have edited my post implementing your suggestion (the request includes the channel_name and and the socket_id right?). But no luck so far. When I use private channel with the javascript of my web app, no problem to authenticate on private channel with the initial implementation I have shown above. I believe the issue is that the webapp doesn't recognize there is a user logged in since it is using laravel passport oauth implementation. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand what you mean by "When I use private channel with the javascript of my web app, no problem to authenticate on private channel with the initial implementation I have shown above." Are you able to check the network tab of the debug console in your browser to see what's returned by your auth endpoint?

Comment: When I register with the regular javascript client of my website without oauth server. For this, I'm using Laravel Echo. Sorry if my explanation is not clear. here is the doc I have followed: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/broadcasting#installing-laravel-echo

Comment: I made it working by removing the oauth middleware for user authentication on the request. So that's a first good step. But the issue now is I need to be able to get user authenticated so I can give proper authorization to the access of the channel... Not sure if I pass the oauth token properly in the pusher request?

Comment: The issue was on my side. The way I was getting the token was wrong hence the issue to authenticate. So the code above is working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @sbkl I'm stuck at the same point as you. Okay, the pusher library returns a token after calling /broadcasting/auth, but Laravel Echo does not suscribe to the channel in the browser. Do you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

edit your auth endpoint like this

```
        $user = auth()->user();

        if ($user) {
            $pusher = new Pusher('auth-key', 'secret', 'app_id');
            $auth= $pusher->socket_auth(Input::get('channel_name'), Input::get('socket_id'));
            $callback = str_replace('\\', '', $_GET['callback']);
            header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
            echo($callback . '(' . $auth . ');');
            return;
        }else {
            header('', true, 403);
            echo "Forbidden";
            return;
        }
```